# Inicializar atributo de tipo puntero en una clase | C++

Tags: c++, punteros

Por la web, encontré el siguiente código de ejemplo para aprender el concepto de polimorfismo. Sin embargo, no me compila

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
 
class Persona {
  public:
   Persona(char *n) { strcpy(nombre, n); }
   void VerNombre() { cout << nombre << endl; }
  protected:
   char nombre[30];
};

class Empleado : public Persona {
  public:
   Empleado(char *n) : Persona(n) {}
   void VerNombre() { 
      cout << "Emp: " << nombre << endl; 
   }
};

class Estudiante : public Persona {
  public:
   Estudiante(char *n) : Persona(n) {}
   void VerNombre() { 
      cout << "Est: " << nombre << endl; 
   }
};

int main() {
   Persona *Pepito = new Estudiante('José'); // Acá me tira error, diciendo "ISO C++ forbids
                                //converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]gcc
   Persona *Carlos = new Empleado("Carlos");

   Carlos->VerNombre();
   Pepito->VerNombre();
   delete Pepito;
   delete Carlos;
   
   return 0;
}
```

Entiendo que el problema surge al intentar inicializar una variable puntero a char, con un string. Navegando, no encuentro de qué forma lograr cargar los nombres "José" y "Carlos". Aclaro que estoy estudiando el concepto de polimorfismo, y por esto es que estoy usando punteros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero esta linea:

```cpp
   Persona *Pepito = new Estudiante('José');
```

Recuerda que los caracteres van entre `''` y los strings entre `""`

Si corriges ese error el programa compila. Lo otro es que estas pasando `const char *` a unos `char *`. Ese es el segundo error.

Por ultimo, este codigo no tiene polimorfismo, ya que no tienes metodos virtuales que sobrecargar. Ya con todos los cambios hechos el codigo queda asi:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
 
class Persona {
  public:
   Persona(const char *n) { strcpy(nombre, n); }
   virtual void VerNombre() { cout << nombre << endl; }
  protected:
   char nombre[30];
};

class Empleado : public Persona {
  public:
   Empleado(const char *n) : Persona(n) {}
   void VerNombre() override { 
      cout << "Emp: " << nombre << endl; 
   }
};

class Estudiante : public Persona {
  public:
   Estudiante(const char *n) : Persona(n) {}
   void VerNombre() override { 
      cout << "Est: " << nombre << endl; 
   }
};

int main() {
   Persona *Pepito = new Estudiante("José"); // Acá me tira error, diciendo "ISO C++ forbids
                                //converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]gcc
   Persona *Carlos = new Empleado("Carlos");

   Carlos->VerNombre();
   Pepito->VerNombre();
   delete Pepito;
   delete Carlos;
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Voy cazando un poco más. Me queda una duda, que inevitablemente me queda desde que aprendí punteros. No entiendo por qué puedo pasar como argumento, al crear el objeto, una cadena de caracteres (const char), siendo que el constructor pide que pase un puntero a const char. Me parecería más lógico que, según como se definió el constructor, yo tenga que pasar como argumento una dirección de memoria. Espero haber sido claro.

Comment: Perdón, sin querer eliminé lo que me respondiste

Comment: Si puede parecer raro, espero haber entendido bien la pregunta. Hasta donde entiendo, pasarlos de esa manera es como si al principio declaras la constante y solo pasaras la direccion de la constante a la funcion

Comment: Lo elimine yo, es que le di enter sin haber terminado @finzeo

Comment: A ver si entendí bien. Mi constructor se define así: Persona(const char *n) { strcpy(nombre, n); }. Si yo paso como parámetro "José", lo que hace el programa primero es crear (sin que se lo pida) una variable n del tipo const char; luego, guarda "José" en la variable n, y crea la variable *n donde guarda la dirección de memoria de la variable n. Al existir esa variable n, es que después puede usar la función strcpy usando, como uno de sus argumentos, n. ¿Está bien?

Comment: Acabo de ver una cosa que creo que puede hacerlo mas facil de entender, te parece llevarlo a un chat?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111550/discussion-between-pablochaches-and-finzeo).

Comment: @finzeo *No entiendo por qué puedo pasar como argumento, al crear el objeto, una cadena de caracteres (const char), siendo que el constructor pide que pase un puntero a const char..* Una cadena literal (como por ejemplo `Hello`) en realidad es un bloque de memoria, cuyo contenido son caracteres, es decir, lo que pasas realmente es la dirección de memoria del primer elemento de la cadena.